# Burninate [abbrevia] Tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

I was asking a question about abbreviations when I came across the tag **[abbrevia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abbrevia)**. This tag has:

**[1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608075/how-do-i-set-a-baseline-folder-in-an-abbrevia-zip-archive)**

**1 answer**

**4 total votes** (answers and questions)

**5 tag-wiki views**

**0 followers**

**177 Question Views** (minus 1 as I viewed it simply to see votes)

And it was created 10 months ago and active 10 months ago, meaning it has lived an active life for a total of.... **less than a month!**

This tag is absolutely ridiculous, please, someone **BURNINATE**! (I'm hoping its Shog9 who does it so I see the satisfying beauty of a fire-breathing dragon with a human arm on mega-steroids yelling "BURNINATED")

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is a script that runs on tags that are sufficiently old with only one question in them, and deletes the tag.

Comment: I think there is about 100 or more questions related to TurboPower Abbrevia, just not using this tag. But let's burn it. I don't think anyone would take the time to retag them nor that we need a tag for every single FOSS project.

Comment: @MichaelT Regardless of the existence of any tag-removing script or program, this tag is not active and not useful. In the wise words of TLama, "let's burn it".

Comment: Then 1) remove it from the question and 2) wait for it to be swept up by the tag cleanup system.  Done.

Comment: ...but...it's a valid thing...it's not esoteric, it exists...

Comment: @RobertHarvey Why is this [status-completed]? There is still a question tagged. (And IMO it appears to be a legitimate tag that doesn't need to be eliminated.)

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Quite right; reversed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The degree to which a tag is (not) used is not grounds for its removal.  If anything, that a tag is used so infrequently is evidence of it being benign (not harmful).